# Custom FONT not displayed for Flutter WebApp (on FireBase) on Android Devices

Tags: android, windows, firebase, flutter, fonts

I deployed my flutter web app to FireBase: https://rotation-time.web.app/#/

Project link in GitHub: https://github.com/ynvgib/rotationtime

```
Container(
      child:
      const Text(
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 10,
          fontFamily: 'iChing',
        ),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
    ),
```

I implemented a Custom Font iching.ttf (unique made iChing Hexagram Characters).
(https://github.com/ynvgib/rotationtime/blob/main/fonts/iching.ttf)

It WORKS in the following cases:

1. on Windows (web version and windows version)
2. apk build installed on Android (so NOT through the WEB)

[WORKING SCREENSHOT ON WINDOWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itwiQ.png)

it **DOES NOT WORK on Android device** (tested on Galaxy S7 and Tab A6):

1. through the browser
2. through installed webapp (through the browser)

[NOT WORKING SCREENSHOT on ANDROID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oCzf.jpg)

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added a code snippet